# Error when trying to insert a variable from C# into MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, string

Here is my code that I'm using to insert values into my database.

```
public void callSQL(string partNumber, string total, string numOfPacks, string dunsNumber,   string serialNumber, string laneNumber)

    {

 MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=testing;UID=root;PASSWORD=********;");

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine(laneNumber);
            MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO test (Part_Number, total, number_of_packs, dunsNumber, serialNumber, truck_number) VALUES (" + partNumber +","+total+","+numOfPacks+","+dunsNumber+","+serialNumber+","+laneNumber+")", myConnection);
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.Write("Done");
            myConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Its really weird what happens. The problem I am getting is with the laneNumber variable. It is a string that I read from the console.

```
 Console.WriteLine("Please enter the date and lane number like so: ddmmyylanenumber.");
        string lanenum = Console.ReadLine();
```

However it only gets inputted into the database when it is all numbers. The moment there is a character in there, I am not able to input anything into the database. It works when I manually change the variable to a string, but not when I use the variable with characters inside. The error I get is this:

"MySQL.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlExectipn (0x8004005): Unknown column 'whatever_i_entered_into_console' in 'field list'

The line that the compiler complains about is the `myCommand.ExectueNonQuery();` line.

Hope this is enough information.
Thanks for the help in advance.

**EDIT**
truck_number is a VARCHAR.

Comment: Don't include the values directly in your SQL - use parameterized SQL. That's the first thing to fix, and if you're still having problems, edit your question to show it.

Comment: @JonSkeet what do you mean parameterized SQL?

Comment: Search for the term and see what you find :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from your comments you mentioned that `truck_number` column is a `VARCHAR` type.

**Problem :**  You are not enclosing the string value `lane_number` within a single quotes.

**Solution :** You need to enclose the string values for `VARCHAR` types within single quotes to send them properly  :

Try This: **(I don't Suggest this)**

```
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO test (Part_Number, total, number_of_packs, dunsNumber, serialNumber, truck_number) VALUES (" + partNumber +","+total+","+numOfPacks+","+dunsNumber+","+serialNumber+",'"+laneNumber+"')", myConnection);
```

**Suggestion :** Your `INSERT INTO` statement is open to `SQL Injection Attacks`. so i would suggest you to use `Parameterised queries` to avoid them.

when you use `parameterised queries` respective types willbe sent properly,so you don't even need to use single quotes while sending string values.

**using Parameterised Queries :**

```
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO test (Part_Number, total, number_of_packs, dunsNumber, serialNumber, truck_number) VALUES (@Part_Number,@total,@number_of_packs,@dunsNumber,@serialNumber,@truck_number)", myConnection);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Part_Number",partNumber);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total",total);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number_of_packs",numOfPacks);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dunsNumber",dunsNumber);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serialNumber",serialNumber);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@truck_number",laneNumber);
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: It is a varchar, I forgot to mention that. I even changed it in my workbench just to make sure. If I manually enter trucknumber as "123abc" it will work, but not when its a variable.

Answer (score 1):

> Make sure that columnNames are correct

Try like ths

```
 MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO test VALUES('" + partNumber +"','"+total+"','"+numOfPacks+"','"+dunsNumber+"','"+serialNumber+"','"+laneNumber+"')", myConnection);
```